# How can I display the users name under a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After a User has posted in my blog-ish website, I would like for the website to post the date of when it was published and the name of the user underneath the post. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about created_at and updated_at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your post model belongs to user model, you can view user name such way:

```
@post.user.name
```

And for timestamps:

```
@post.created_at
```

Answer (score 1):

For your created and updated time you can use `created_at` and `updated_at` with `Timestamps`, in which `created_at` gives the created date/time and `updated_at` gives latest updated date/time. For your publish date you can use one extra field ex, publish_at of type date/time which updated when you publish the article,